Pointwise convergence of positive harmonic functions implies compact convergence?
While working through the book Harmonic Function Theory by Sheldon Axler, Paul Bourdon, and Wade Ramey, I came across the following exercise:

Chapter 3, Exercise 11. Prove that a pointwise convergent sequence of positive harmonic functions on $\Omega$ converges uniformly on compact subsets of $\Omega$.

Although it hasn't been explicitly mentioned, I suspect $\Omega$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ for $n\ge 2$.
The only approach I can see is to begin with a pointwise convergent sequence $(u_n)$ of positive harmonic functions and attempt to prove, using Harnack's inequality that $(u_n)$ is uniformly Cauchy on compact subsets of $\Omega$. The problem with this approach is that $u_m - u_n$ may not be a positive harmonic function on $\Omega$.
Any advice on how to proceed would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: (An observation) Let $K\subseteq\Omega$ be compact and $C > 0$ be the constant furnished by Harnack's inequality. Fix $x_0\in K$. Since $(u_n(x_0))$ converges, it must be bounded, say $u_n(x_0)\le M$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Due to Harnack's inequality, $u_n(x)\le CM$ for all $x\in K$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$. In other words, $(u_n)$ is uniformly bounded on compact subsets of $\Omega$. Using Montel's theorem (Theorem 2.6 in the aforementioned book), we conclude that there is a uniformly convergent subsequence $(u_{n_k})$.
Again, this isn't sufficient since there are pointwise convergent sequences with uniformly convergent subsequences.

I have been able to do this exercise. I'm adding my answer for posterity.
I quote from the book:

2.4 (Cauchy's Estimates) Let $\alpha$ be a multi-index. Then there is a positive constant $C_\alpha$ such that
\begin{equation*}
    |D^\alpha u(a)| \le\frac{C_\alpha M}{r^{|\alpha|}}
\end{equation*}
for all functions $u$ harmonic and bounded by $M$ on $B(a, r)$.

Using the above, we prove a result about equicontinuity.

Lemma. Let $(u_n)$ be a sequence of harmonic functions on an open set $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb{R}^m$ that is uniformly bounded on compact subsets. Then $(u_n)$ is equicontinuous on every compact subset of $\Omega$.

Proof. It suffices to show pointwise equicontinuity. Let $a\in\Omega$ and $R > 0$ such that $\overline B(a, 2R)\subseteq\Omega$. There is an $M > 0$ such that $|u_n|\le M$ on $\overline B(a, 2R)$. For any $x\in B(a, R)$, we have
\begin{equation*}
    |u_n(x) - u_n(a)|\le m\left(\sup_{B(a, R)} |\nabla u_n|\right)|x - a|\le m\frac{C_1M}{r}|x - a|,
\end{equation*}
where the second inequality follows from Cauchy's estimates, since $B(y, R)\subseteq B(a, 2R)$ for all $y\in B(a, R)$. Pointwise equicontinuity follows from the above inequality. $\square$
Returning to the exercise, let $(u_n)$ be the pointwise convergent sequence of positive harmonic functions and $K\subseteq\Omega$ be a compact set. Choose $x_0\in K$ and let $C > 0$ be the constant furnished by Harnack's inequality for $K$. Since $(u_n(x_0))$ is convergent, it is bounded by some $M > 0$. Consequently, for any $y\in K$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $0\le u_n(y)\le Cu_n(x_0)\le CM$. In other words, $(u_n)$ is uniformly bounded on compact subsets of $\Omega$ and hence, is equicontinuous on compact subsets, whence compact convergence follows. $\blacksquare$
